# Probability of at least s amounts of at least k consecutive successes in a Bernoulli trial

Tags: probability

I am not in the fields of mathematics, I'm just looking for a formula to a real life problem.

I have `n` independents trials of the same event `E` which has a individual probability `p` of success.

What is the probability to have *at least* `s` amounts of *at least* `k` successes in a row, and where could I type this formula (wolfram or another free site or free software or code) so that I just enter `p,k,n,s` and it gives me the response ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new answer that is not a formula you can type into a calculator, but more correct. After $k$ successful trials, we can stop because we have done it. So, we want to know the probability of $k$ trials in a row $(p)^k$ given that

- The last trial was a failure, as otherwise it could be counted in our one beforehand
- There were not $k$ consecutive trials in the first $i-1$ trials, where $i$ is the start of our $1^{st}$ successful trial in the string of $k$

Then, we let $a_i$ be the probability that within $i - 1$ trials, we don't have $k$ successes in a row. If the probability we have for $k$ trials in a row out of $n$ total is denoted $C_n^k$, we would have $1 - C_{i-1}^k$ probability. Then you would add all of these recursively defined formulas up. So, if you were to program it, a function would be:

$$C_n^k = p^k + \sum_{i=2}^{n-k+1}(1-C_{i-1}^k )(1-p)(p)^k$$

I have not attempted this currently, but I will try soon, and if it's wrong I will attempt to fix it again. Sorry I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: If I type `$$\sum_{i=k}^n (n-i+1) (p)^i$$ where p=0.5, n=10, k=3`, (basically, I want to know the probability of having at least 3 consecutive heads in 10 coin tosses) in wolfram, it returns me 1.75098, how can a probability be greater than 1 ?

Comment: The nice thing about probability is that we know absolutely wolfram is wrong in this case.

Comment: @Robert Murray, I'm sorry, I forgot to add that I'm interested in at least s amounts of such consecutive successes, instead of just one. Could you please add this component to your answer ?

Comment: I have found [this link](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath341.htm) which seems to answer the first part of the question. But how to generalize to "at least s successes" instead of just 1 ?